# How to apply conditions on data coming from pipes

Tags: angular, typescript

I implement a pipe which gets two value and finds the duration between them,it counts the duration in days if duration is less than 1 day it returns 0, but i don't want to show 0 in that case, i want to display "recently" if duration is less than a day.

HTML

```
     <div>{{firstdate | myPipe : agent.lastUpdated}} d ago</div>
```

pipe.ts

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({
name: 'myPipe',
pure: true

  })
 export class durationPipe implements PipeTransform{

transform(firstDate:any , secondDate:any):any{
   if(!firstDate || !secondDate){
       return firstDate;
   }

   const dropdt:any = new Date(firstDate);
  const pickdt:any = new Date(secondDate);
      const time = +((firstDate - secondDate) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
    //   console.log("this is currentTime "+firstDate);
    //   console.log("this is userTime "+secondDate);
     const a = time.toString().split('.',1);
    // console.log("time is "+a);
      return a;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of cause in implementing such task.

First one is quick but quite bad for performance because of relatively a lot of bindings:

```
<div>
  <span *ngIf="firstdate | myPipe : agent.lastUpdated">
    {{firstdate | myPipe : agent.lastUpdated}} d ago
  </span>
  <span *ngIf="!(firstdate | myPipe : agent.lastUpdated)">
    recently
  </span>
</div>
```

I'd suggest you create two pipes: one for calculating the difference in days and the second one to display correctly.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'dayDiff',
  pure: true
})
export class DayDiff implements PipeTransform {
  private millisecondsInDay = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
  transform(from: any , till: any): any {
     if(!from || !till){
         return from;
     }
     const fromDate = new Date(from);
     const tillDate = new Date(till);
     return Math.floor((firstDate - secondDate) / this.millisecondsInDay);
  }
}

...

@Pipe({
  name: 'dayDiffDisplay',
  pure: true
})
export class DayDiffDisplay implements PipeTransform {
  transform(diff: number): any {
     if(!diff){
         return 'recently';
     }
     return `${diff} d ago`;
  }
}
```

So the usage is simply:

```
{{firstdate | dayDiff : agent.lastUpdated | dayDiffDisplay}}
```

Comment: Thanks , both of your answers are valid

Comment: but i have a question, should i implement first suggestion? because 2 pipe takes more time than binding

Comment: hm, actually the second approach should work faster I think because there are only two bindings here (2 pipes) and also pipes are pure so that if value didn't change then no update required  for angular. In the first case two ngifs will be processed on each change detection with pipe in ngif expression and if first one is ok then one more pipe will be processed. But these are just my suspicions and if you checked that the first one is faster then you can use it.